# C# making a datagrid from datatable leaves my rows empty (Column names dateTime)

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, datatable, datagrid

When I send my datatable to dataGrid before transpose, all is ok. But after transpose the datatable my column name get dataTime values and the rest of the datagrid table is empty.

transpose method:

```
private DataTable Transpose(DataTable dt)
    {
        DataTable dtNew = new DataTable();

        //adding columns    
        for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            dtNew.Columns.Add(i.ToString());
        }



        //Changing Column Captions: 
        //dtNew.Columns[0].ColumnName = " ";

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            //For dateTime columns use like below
            dtNew.Columns[i + 1].ColumnName = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString()).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
            //Else just assign the ItermArry[0] to the columnName prooperty
        }

        //Adding Row Data
        for (int k = 1; k < dt.Columns.Count; k++)
        {
            DataRow r = dtNew.NewRow();
            r[0] = dt.Columns[k].ToString();
            for (int j = 1; j <= dt.Rows.Count; j++)
                r[j] = dt.Rows[j - 1][k];
            dtNew.Rows.Add(r);
        }

        return dtNew;
```

[IMG: my dataGrid before transpose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XZfV.png)

[IMG: my datagrid after transpose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhOtl.png)

I tryed multiple ways to solve this issue but i cant get why is this happening. Looks like that if i change the column name for another string beside the date it works.

my code for the datagrid is:

```
dataGrid_x.ItemsSource = x.Tables[listBox_sites.SelectedItem.ToString()].AsDataView();
        dataGrid_y.DataContext = y.Tables[listBox_sites.SelectedItem.ToString()].DefaultView;
        dataGrid_t.DataContext = t.Tables[listBox_sites.SelectedItem.ToString()].DefaultView;
        dataGrid_h.DataContext = h.Tables[listBox_sites.SelectedItem.ToString()].DefaultView;
```

Comment: probably similar issue with [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42482663/data-is-visible-in-dataset-visualizer-but-does-not-show-in-a-datagrid)

Comment: Yes it is. Thank you and Sorry to post another similar problem. Dind't found that one.

Comment: Problem solved. Saw the solution in the other [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42482663/data-is-visible-in-dataset-visualizer-but-does-not-show-in-a-datagrid).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Data is visible in DataSet visualizer but does not show in a DataGrid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42482663/data-is-visible-in-dataset-visualizer-but-does-not-show-in-a-datagrid)