# DataTable into Datagrid binding error

Tags: c#, wpf, epplus

I populate a `DataTable` with an Excel file, then I assign this `DataTable` to the `ItemSource` of my `DataGrid`, all the columns and rows are fine, except for the last one which throws:

> "System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Y Error Est' property not found on 'object' ''DataRowView' (HashCode=64398613)'. BindingExpression:Path=Y Error Est. 1 (Class 1); 
>   DataItem='DataRowView' (HashCode=64398613); 
>   target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); 
>   target property is 'Text' (type 'String')"`

Here's the populate function:

```
using (var pck = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage())
{
    using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(dialog.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
    {
        pck.Load(fileStream);
    }

    ExcelWorksheet worksheet = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
    DataTable tbl = new DataTable();

    //Column Headers
    foreach (ExcelRangeBase firstRowCell in worksheet.Cells[9, 2, 9, worksheet.Dimension.End.Column])
    {
        tbl.Columns.Add(firstRowCell.Text);
    }

    Int32 startRow = 10;
    for (Int32 rowNum = startRow; rowNum <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Row; rowNum++)
    {
        ExcelRange range = worksheet.Cells[rowNum, 2, rowNum, worksheet.Dimension.End.Column];

        DataRow row = tbl.Rows.Add();

        foreach (ExcelRangeBase cell in range)
        {
            //tbl.Rows.Add(cell.Text);
            row[cell.Start.Column-2] = cell.Text;
        }
    }
    DTGrid.ItemsSource = tbl.AsDataView();
}
```

Here the WPF Binding:

```
<DataGrid Name="DTGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DTGrid.ItemsSource}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" AutoGenerateColumns="true"></DataGrid>
```

I'm following the MVVM pattern, just in case someone ask, this is happening on my ViewModel for the View.

I know the error is quite specific and clear, but all the columns are fine except for that one, and I have also checked the DataType of the cell in Excel and is the same as the others, so I'm quite lost.

Any one can help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the value of `worksheet.Dimension.End.Column`?

Comment: 30, that is only the number of columns where it ends the Range.

Comment: So you checked the value during execution and it was as expected?

Comment: Exactly, DataRow has everything fine, and all the columns with all the values, the problem is (I assume) in the DTGrid.ItemSource = tbl.AsDataView();

Comment: in your DataGrid, why are you using grid.row="1" and grid.column and columnspan.  Is this grid inside another grid?

Comment: The DataGrid is inside the main Grid from the window. You have to tell where you want the control, in this case the DataGrid.

Comment: You solved it, Thanks @ASh, I will update with an answer and redirect to yours on that post.

Comment: @TareqB., there should be an option for you to close question as duplicate, I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was actually the ColumnName, the ColumnName is use to create the binding path, a better explanation can be found on @ASh answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42482663/data-is-visible-in-dataset-visualizer-but-does-not-show-in-a-datagrid)

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the correct answer, but I think I remember that excel empty cells are classed a null and not string empty, you might have to adapt you query to replace nulls with empty strings. Your error complains about the expected value requiring being a string
Hope this is useful.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, sadly there is non empty cell on the file. But I didn't know that, thanks for pointing it out. =D

Comment: Actually then again looking again at your code, would it be better to user Cell.Value as opposed to Cell.Text.

Comment: I just tested changing to Cell.Value and got the same error.

Comment: Finally, could it be to do with index start values, id datatables start at index 0. excel I think starts a index 1. you might be trying to read the row past the end of the worksheet dimension.

Comment: Yep, that is the first thing I thougth, but, I have checked the other columns and rows and everything is where it should be (same place as in the original Excel file).

Comment: Humour me, change  rowNum <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Row to  rowNum < worksheet.Dimension.End.Row

Comment: Tested, Same result =(

Comment: what happens when you remove ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DTGrid.ItemsSource}"  from the xml

Comment: what would you expect to happen?  An empty grid, i am sure.  How does that help?

Comment: You are setting the ItemsSource in the code behind... and not using binding as i'd expect it to be used.

Comment: Ahhh, yes.  If he is binding in the code-behind, why have the source specified in the data-grid.

Comment: Yes, Tareq B, let us know if removing the binding from the xml fixes the error.

Comment: He probably should strip that datagrid to nothing more than the name and the autogeneratecolumns

Comment: Yes and no, he'll still need the Grid.Row, Rowspan, GridSpan and Column to position it correctly in his view

Comment: Well, if I delete the binding in the XAML then there is nothing to be shown because the XAML doesn't know about the DTGrid inside the ViewModel.

Tested, and nothing is shown.

Comment: This post might help you out. it's about binding a datagrid to an excel document, and in the example you do not need to state the itemssource binding on the XAML - http://www.codescratcher.com/wpf/import-excel-file-datagrid-wpf/ also ensure you are closing and disposing of the excel document or it may get caught in memory...(running in the background unseen)

Comment: The post doesn't use the MVVM pattern design, therefore the "dtGrid" is referencing directly to the DataGrid in the XAML.
When you use the MVVM desing, you are separating both, the View (xaml) and the code behind, the code goes into the ViewModel class, you have to bind with your properties and fields in concordance with the View.

Comment: IN that case you will need to create a class which implements INotifyPropertychanged in the code. and in add that as an ObservableCollection<tabledata> = dtData, and bind the datatable to the new property In the code behind set the created datatable to the property dtData instead of the itemssource. See the following post. [Here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/be08fb20-5071-423e-8e21-205520bcb882/binding-datagrid-from-database-through-observable-collection-in-mvvm-wpf?forum=wpf)

Comment: I think you are confuse, that will work if I have a WhateverRepresentationOfMyRow_Object, kind of class that represents a row in my table. Then you bind it to the ObservableCollection<YourObject> and this into the DataGrid. 
It is no the case as I generated the DataTable from an Excel file in which the Columns can change, means, I create the DataTable columns dinamically and I cannot make a default object for it.