# C# DataTable DataGrid special character "/" (slash) in column names

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, binding, datagrid

I would like to display a table of strings in C# using a DataGrid. The column names are dynamically generated (i.e. not known at compile time).

Here is an example:

[image]

Here, the numbers have been converted to strings.

I am using a DataTable as the source for the DataGrid which contains the whole table (rows and column headers). However, I have the problem that the values in column "climate w/change" are not shown in the DataGrid. Instead I get the following error message on the Console

```
"BindingExpression path error: 'climate  w' property not found on 'object' 
''DataRowView' (HashCode=22429696)'. BindingExpression:Path=climate  
w/change; DataItem='DataRowView' (HashCode=22429696); target element is 
'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')"
```

I understand that this is due to the slash ("/") in the column name which is interpreted as a binding expression.

My questions are

1. Is there a way to switch off that behavior, i.e. that column names are interpreted as binding expressions? Since I provide a DataTable with all values and headers for the rows and columns, none of the data values need to be computed based on the column name. Also the column "human toxicity" has no problems although there does not exists a property called HumanToxicity.
2. If I cannot use DataTable as the source for the DataGrid to achieve the above, which is the correct data structure to be used?

Here is the code to generate the DataTable.

```
    public DataTable PaValues { get; set; }

    private void CreateDataSet()
    {
        var dt = new DataTable("Perturbation Analysis");
        List<String> ics = _perturbationAnalysis.ImpactCatagories();
        dt.Columns.Add("Parameters");

        foreach (var ic in ics)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(Sanatize(ic));
        }
        foreach (var parameter in _perturbationAnalysis.ParameterNames())
        {
            var dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = parameter;
            for (int i = 0; i < ics.Count; i++)
            {
                dr[i+1] = _perturbationAnalysis[parameter, ics[i]].ToString();
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        PaValues = dt;
    }

    private string Sanatize(string ic)
    {
        //return ic.Replace("/", "[/]").Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "").Replace(".", " ");
        //return "[" + ic + "]";
        return ic;

    }
```

Here is the excerpt from the XAML file

```
            <DataGrid
                x:Name="PAGrid"
                CanUserAddRows="False" 
                CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                ClipboardCopyMode="IncludeHeader"
                FrozenColumnCount="1"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PaValues,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                Style="{StaticResource DataGridStyle}"
                IsReadOnly="True">
            </DataGrid>
```

As proposed in the comments, I have added an AutoGeneratingColumn handler, which changes the binding to use square brackets:

```
    private void PaViewAutoGeneratingColumnHandler(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Column = new DataGridTextColumn
        {
            Binding = new Binding("[" + e.Column.Header + "]"), Header=e.Column.Header

        };
    }
```

It now works fine for "climate w/change", but it does not work for a column named "EDIP2003 w/o LT, acidification w/o LT, acidification w/o LT", which is a real life example used by the customer. The error message is the same as before

```
BindingExpression path error: '[]' property not found on 'object' ''DataRowView' (HashCode=56876317)'. 
BindingExpression:Path=[EDIP2003 w/o LT, acidification w/o LT, acidification w/o LT]
```

Comment: You might want to use DataGrid column's `Header` property instead of actual column name in DataTable. With such approach, column names wouldn't be the problem.

Comment: Replace the slash with an underscore.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Data is visible in DataSet visualizer but does not show in a DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42482663/data-is-visible-in-dataset-visualizer-but-does-not-show-in-a-datagrid)

Comment: @jdweng This is the workaround that I am currently using, but not very nice. The column names come from the customer, and thus should appear as the customer has written them.

Comment: @ASh I tried "climate w[/]change" and "[climate w/change]" as mentioned in the article, but both don't work. The first one gives the same error message as before, the second one "System.Windows.Data Error: 17 : Cannot get 'Item[]' value (type 'Object') from '' (type 'DataRowView'). BindingExpression:Path=[climate  w/change];"

Comment: @AlexSeleznyov I am using xaml to do describe the DataGrid and provide a binding to the DataTable as the source. How do I access the DataGrid programmatically and still use the xaml file?

Comment: @Hubert, please show the code where you create DataTable and DataGrid

Comment: @Hubert wire up a handler for https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratedcolumns(v=vs.110).aspx event and you'll be able to process columns there.

Comment: @Hubert, did you try to add AutoGeneratedColumns handler and change binding paths? (instead of changing column names in Sanatize method)

Comment: @AlexSeleznyov I have now added an AutoGeneratingColumn handler (see the original question). But using [ and ] only works partially. I am trying to experiment with other values for the Binding property. I have used ".", but then I get the string "DataRowView"; I have also tried to remove all the special characters in the binding, but then the value is not found anymore.

Comment: @Hubert I must've been unclear. I suggested you name your columns `Col1`-`ColN`, for example, and then using some kind of logic (map, list, whatever) assign `ColX`'s `Header` property to meaningful value, i.e. `My/col/header@`, keeping `Binding` working.

Comment: @AlexSeleznyov I didn't get that from your link, but I tried it now and it works. But it is uuuuugly. I have to use fake column names and then patch them in the view with access to the view model from the code behind the xaml file to access the real column names for which I have to create a public property in the view model. I am surprised that such an easy problem does not have an easy solution but requires to hack the code. In any case, thank you all a lot. I wouldn't have been able to find the solution by myself.

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the documentation on [PropertyPath syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/propertypath-xaml-syntax), we can see why the strings fail to map.

The first one, which you already pointed out and could fix, is the slash `/`:

> #### Source Traversal (Binding to Hierarchies of Collections)
>
> ```
> <object Path="propertyName/propertyNameX" .../>
> ```
>
> The / in this syntax is used to navigate within a hierarchical data source object, and multiple steps into the hierarchy with successive / characters are supported.

This is fixed by using an indexer (`[]`).

However, the indexer format supports multiple indexers, separated by comma:

> #### Multiple Indexers
>
> ```
> <object Path="[index1,index2...]" .../>
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> <object Path="propertyName[index,index2...]" .../>
> ```
>
> If a given object supports multiple indexers, those indexers can be specified in order, similar to an array referencing syntax. The object in question can be either the current context or the value of a property that contains a multiple index object.

If we look further, we can see that we can escape the comma using the following syntax:

> #### Escapes for Property Path Strings
>
> For certain business objects, you might encounter a case where the property path string requires an escape sequence in order to parse correctly. The need to escape should be rare, because many of these characters have similar naming-interaction issues in languages that would typically be used to define the business object.
>
> - Inside indexers ([ ]), the caret character (^) escapes the next character.

---

Using all of this, I came up with the following solution to escape everything while still using auto-generated columns. It might be overkill, but it guarantees that the string is interpreted correctly.

```
private void PaViewAutoGeneratingColumnHandler(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    var columnName = (string)e.Column.Header;

    // We'll build a string with escaped characters.
    // The capacity is the length times 2 (for the carets),
    // plus 2 for the square brackets.
    // This is not optimized for multi-character glyphs, like emojis

    var bindingBuilder = new StringBuilder(columnName.Length * 2 + 2);

    bindingBuilder.Append('[');
    foreach (var c in columnName)
    {
        bindingBuilder.Append('^');
        bindingBuilder.Append(c);
    }
    bindingBuilder.Append(']');

    e.Column = new DataGridTextColumn
    {
        Binding = new Binding(bindingBuilder.ToString()),
        Header = e.Column.Header,
    };
}
```