# Trasform a datatable in pivot for datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I need to transform a datatable into a pivot table, but I can't value the fields, at least in the datagrid in WPF I don't see it this is my code

my select data

```
"SELECT [Giorno] ,[Turno] ,[Ispettori] ,[Totale] FROM TABLE WHERE Giorno >= '2020.02.29' and Giorno <= '2020.02.29' ORDER BY [Giorno], [Turno]";
```

With the result I enhance my datatable

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
```

Add a column for calc

```
dt.Columns.Add("TotalTurno");

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
  {
      row["TotalTurno"] = row[dt.Columns[3]] + "/" + row[dt.Columns[2]];
  }
```

Remove the column that I don't need

```
 dt.Columns.Remove("Ispettori");
 dt.Columns.Remove("Totale");
```

I extrapolate the columns that I have to add to the datatable (they must be unique)

```
string[] uniqueAncType = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<System.DateTime>("Giorno").ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")).Distinct().ToArray();
```

DataTable pivot = new DataTable();
pivot.Columns.Add("Turno");

Add the column to a pivot datatable

```
foreach (string col in uniqueAncType)
{
    pivot.Columns.Add(col, typeof(string));
}
```

I group the data to put it in the datatable pivot

```
var groups = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => new {
                    opr_dt = x.Field<DateTime>("Giorno").ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
                    opr_tt = x.Field<string>("TotalTurno"),
                    opr_turno = x.Field<string>("Turno"),
                }).ToList();
```

Add value to the pivot

```
foreach (var group in groups)
{
    DataRow newRow = pivot.NewRow();
    newRow["Turno"] = group.Key.opr_turno;

    foreach (DataRow ancType in group)
    {
         newRow[group.Key.opr_dt] = group.Key.opr_tt;
          pivot.Rows.Add(newRow);
     }
}
```

Obtain this ... :((( 
I don't have the values ​​in the column .. can you help me understand why?

[image]

Comment: it might be [the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42482663/1506454)

Comment: Thanks ... I resolved

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Data is visible in DataSet visualizer but does not show in a DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42482663/data-is-visible-in-dataset-visualizer-but-does-not-show-in-a-datagrid)

Comment: Yes, now it work