# My DataGrid with WPF C# is not populating col 1 but is populating the other columns

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

WPF C#, trying to populate a data grid and it's skipping column 1 for some reason...
I'm still getting used to WPF so, i suspect it's some kind of default value or setting in properties.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Subtest/Subdomain");
dt.Columns.Add("Standard & Scaled Scores");
dt.Columns.Add("Percentile");
dt.Columns.Add("Description");

dt.Rows.Add("1","2","3","4");

dataGridBayley4.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGridBayley4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="315" Margin="76,131,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="638" SelectedIndex="0" Grid.RowSpan="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
```

I've been researching for a couple hours with no luck...I've tried properties and even see the value when i do a messagebox.show for dt[0][0]

Comment: try `dt.Columns.Add("[Subtest/Subdomain]");`. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42482663/data-is-visible-in-dataset-visualizer-but-does-not-show-in-a-datagrid

Comment: Thanks, i removed special characters and that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I had special characters in my column name that was causing the interference.